# I keep getting a postgrator-cli error on heroku npm deploy

Tags: postgresql, heroku, npm

I'm trying to deploy an app to heroku but for some reason when I run the deploy command I keep on getting this error:

```
rator-cli\postgrator-cli.js:143
        rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Zackr\Documents\node\noteful-exercise\noteful-server\node_modules\postgrator-cli\postgrator-cli.js:143:33
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:327:5)
    at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:474:12)
    at Socket.ondata (readline.js:186:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! noteful-server@1.0.0 migrate: `postgrator --config postgrator-config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the noteful-server@1.0.0 migrate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zackr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T22_04_36_447Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! noteful-server@1.0.0 migrate:production: `env SSL=true DATABASE_URL=$postgres://rwdhntkhuroptu:48522106b9f5aaf0890905df7abe67c75710e00aba50b80edcf01a07d5cbe918@ec2-52-203-49-58.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dcgq78oje0lmb6 npm run migrate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the noteful-server@1.0.0 migrate:production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zackr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T22_04_36_547Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! noteful-server@1.0.0 postdeploy: `npm run migrate:production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the noteful-server@1.0.0 postdeploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zackr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T22_04_36_614Z-debug.log
```

The scripts for my package.json is:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require test/setup.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "migrate": "postgrator --config postgrator-config.js",
    "migrate:test": "env NODE_ENV=test npm run migrate",
    "migrate:production": "env SSL=true DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) npm run migrate",
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "predeploy": "npm audit && npm run migrate:production",
    "deploy": "git push heroku main"
  },
```

I have the connection string and url for the database and the normal migration worked until I changed the url to the heroku URL instead of my local host server.

Comment: What versions of Node.js and npm are you running?

Comment: I am using node version 6.14.6

Answer (score 1):

Node.js 6 was end-of-lifed in April 2018. It has known security vulnerabilities and most libraries don't support it. Update to at least Node.js 10.x, and preferably 14.x.

Current version of postgrator-cli is 4.0.0 and it explicitly doesn't support Node.js prior to 10.x. The last version of postgrator-cli to support Node.js 6.x was postgrator-cli 3.2.0, published in September 2019. So if you cannot upgrade Node.js, another option is to downgrade postgrator-cli to 3.2.0.

Comment: I am using postgrator-cli 3.2.0 though

Comment: Based on the stack trace you provided, I can say with certainty that you were running postgrator-cli 4.0.0 to get that stack trace and not postragtor-cli 3.2.0. I install 4.0.0 and look at line 143 of postgrator-cli.js and it matches your stack trace. In 3.2.0, it does not.

The good news is that this means that if you do `npm install --save-dev postgrator-cli@3.2.0` and try again, it just might work. I'd still recommend you upgrade Node.js rather than downgrade postgrator-cli, though.

Comment: Wait you may be right, strange. I was sure I typed "npm install postgrator-cli@3.2.0". Let me try again.

Comment: Now I keep on getting a new error and I have no idea whats causing it.